# How should I design my relational tables?

Tags: database, postgresql, data-structures, relational-database, powerbi

I am curious to the practicality of structuring my database. Imagine I want to conduct a survey, asking a group of students what are their top 3 preferences out of 10 options. **The objective is to find out ranking of the 10 options by looking at the count of students' choices**.

Initially, my thought process is to create the following relational tables.

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    personID BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    personName VARCHAR(50));

CREATE TABLE preference (
    preferenceID BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    personID INT REFERENCES person(personID),
    preference1 VARCHAR(50),
    preference2 VARCHAR(50),
    preference3 VARCHAR(50));
```

But I begin to stumble on achieving my objective. Since the count of each preference has to be considered in all 3 columns, my current solution is to then manipulate my data (using Excel) until I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE preferenceV2 (
    personID INT,
    preference VARCHAR(50));
```

Here, `personID` is no longer PK nor is it unique, and `preference` can be either of the 10 options. Now, I can achieve my objective by counting the number of votes for each preference and rank them accordingly (through use of PowerBI for example).

However, I realised I end up not leveraging on relational database and the process of manipulating into table `preferenceV2` is manual and prone to errors. What should be the best way for me to approach this?

Comment: *"top 3 preferences out of 10 options"*: is that 3 unranked out of 10 options, or 1st; 2nd; 3rd ranked out of 10 options ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have:

```
CREATE TABLE preferences (
    preferenceID BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    personID INT REFERENCES person(personID),
    preference VARCHAR(50)
```

So if one person have 3 preference you would have

```
   preferenceID personID preference 
        1          1         A
        2          1         B
        3          1         C
        4          2         B
        5          2         C
        6          2         D
```

In this case you can do

```
  SELECT preference, COUNT(preference)
  FROM preferences 
  GROUP BY preference
```